# how to send values to function using feed_dict in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I'm beginner in **tensorflow** and i'm working on a project which i want to send values to a placeholder and use this placeholder in a function so i will simplify what i want.

**This is a simple code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import glob
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[1])

def fun():
    print(x)
    return x

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(fun(),feed_dict={x:[5.]})
```

I want to use **X** value inside the function but when i print it i get the shape only however i used **sess.run** to run the function so that i expect to print the value not the shape but also when i use **print(sess.run(x))** it give me error and say **i must feed X with value** so what am i missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write it like that:

```
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[1])


def fun():
    return x


with tf.Session() as sess:
    y=sess.run(fun(),feed_dict={x:[5.]})
    print(y)
```

Comment: Why i need to send X to the function it is a global variable ? ,, however when i send it to the function it print only the tensorobject also  and i want to use it's value inside some code in the function not after sess.run

Comment: You don't have to send X, see my edited response. The code that I wrote enables you to use the value inside y. You need to assign it to a variable if you want to use it, which is why it is written "y=...".

Comment: No i want to use X value inside Fun() , i used the same manner in a project and i want to use the placeholder value inside the function in some code and this syntax of feeding doesn't send the value to it and i cant use it's value and give me only the tensor object.

Comment: You can use it inside. For example, if you do def fun():
    a=3*x
    return a, and then run the session and print y you will get [15.]

Comment: As long as fun() doesn't get an input, you can run y=sess.run(fun(),feed_dict={x:[5.]}) (that is, you are not sending x to fun). Had you defined fun with x as an input, you would have to pass the input when running the session, so it would have been y=sess.run(fun(x),feed_dict={x:[5.]})